# sending email using static HTML template in Spring MVC application

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have a requirement in my Spring MVC 3 based application to send transaction details to client and business and to send periodic newsletters to clients. I know how to send email using Spring by i am confused about the ways i can create an email HTML body. I have found a solution like - www.thymeleaf.org but not sure if it will be efficient or not.

I can use a service like mail chimp for sending newsletter but i have to have an in-house solution for sending email after each translation. Can someone please guide me how can i create dynamic email using static HTML templates which can be quickly populated with values and send as an email.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `String.format()`, or `MessageFormat.format()` or, if you need more power (like loops, if tests, etc.), use FreeMarker or Velocity.